# draw a rectangle then draw a line clipped to that rectangle

Tags: createjs

Can someone explain the concepts/actions required to do the following:

On my stage I add a myShape then draw a rectangle using the its .graphics. Then I want to draw lines on that rectangle but have them clip automatically to the rectangle i.e. so they don't leak onto the rest of the stage.

It looks as if I could do this using a mask but I am wondering if there is something much simpler I am not understanding.

Comment: Please post some of the code associated with what  you are doing.

Comment: Masking is the best way, without getting into a bunch of math.